# Measure of overlap of plane figures

Tags: area

Do you know if there is any measure which quantifies how much two different plane figures overlap?

if $A_1$, $A_2$ denote the areas of figure $1$ and $2$ respectively, and their overlap area is $A_{\text{over}}$, then the measure $d$ can be define as $d = \dfrac{A_{\text{over}}}{A_1 + A_2}$? Is there any mathematical definition?

Comment: I'm not a mathematician, so I was wondering whether or not exist such a overlap measure.

Comment: The [size of the symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference#Symmetric_difference_on_measure_spaces) is used in measure theory.

Comment: $d$ has no dimension: if you enlarge the figure to 400%, the quantity remains unchanged, contrarily to useful geometric units of measures.

Comment: @GNUSupporter Yes, those angles are useless in geometry.

Comment: @zambawithkolbasa My bad.  I wanted to say "usual".  Nice catch for my typo.

Comment: You just gave a mathematical definition. Looks okay to me.